# DataTable not able to wrap text inside DataCell - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, datatables-1.10

I am not able to wrap the text inside the DataCell in the DataTable widget in Flutter. Tried putting DataCell into a container and assign width but did not work. Looking for some solution to fix this.

[image: The text in row 1 should get wrap so the other column don't overlfow]

The code for the data table is below. This expanded widget is inside a column with some other widgets on top.

```
 Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: DataTable(
                    columnSpacing: 5,
                    columns: <DataColumn>[
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Container(
                          width: 30,
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              "Itemm",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Container(
                          width: 30,
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              "Price",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Container(
                          width: 30,
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              "Quantity",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Container(
                          width: 30,
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              "Discount %",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      DataColumn(
                        label: Container(
                          width: 30,
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(
                              "Total",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                    rows: bill
                        .map((element) => DataRow(
                              cells: <DataCell>[
                                DataCell(
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(
                                      element.itemName,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(element.price),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(element.quantity),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(element.discount),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Text(element.total),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ))
                        .toList())),
          ),
```

Thanks

Comment: Since the sentence you are writing is one word long it will not be wrapped.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this with multiple words. This is just an example in real data there will be a proper sentence with multiple words.

Comment: like this Text('word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7')

Comment: Okay....but is there any way to wrap a single long word?

Comment: Maybe there is no way

Comment: You may have to create a table with Column and Row

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not getting your data, I can not solve the problem, but you can try the below way.

```
Container(
   width: 100,
   child: 
     Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
    )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but I have tried doing this but this does not worked.

Comment: Did you tried with putting this (Container and text) inside the dataCell in DataTable widget?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this like that

```
SizeBox(width: 100,


child: 
     Text("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"),
    )
```